C++ How to return a immutable (on all levels) vector of pointers to objects?
I read this somewhere:
const std::vector<const Target*>& getTargets() const {
        return *reinterpret_cast<const std::vector<const Target *> *>(&targets);
}

where
std::vector<Target*> targets;

Is a private member of an object.
Is this good practice?
The above seems to work as intended.

The reinterpret_cast is an indicator that something suspect is going on.  And, indeed, it is doing something that I consider "bad practice", which is undefined behavior.  The above seems to work as intented.  That's the hilarious part about undefined behavior, it can seem to work as intended.  It is the road paved with good intentions.

That code will make a lot of assumptions on the lifetime of the objects it points to. So it maybe alright but it really depends on the design. "Seems to work as intended" is not good enough (I see too many developers stop there, so you asking about this is a good sign), where is the design, where are the unit tests etc... (

There's also the fundamentally flawed idea of returning a const T and assuming that it's immutable. Even if you return a const T temporary, the caller is likely using that temporary to initialize a non-const T.

You have asked 2 questions.  The answer to these two questions is not the same answer.  One question is "how do I do X?" and the other is "is this solution valid?".  People have marked your second question as a duplicate of "no, that solution is not valid" without answering your first question.

Afaik vector content cannot be immutable, that's not within its capability. Content type should be assignable.  const Target * is  not immutable though, the pointed-at object is. This requires a different approach, involving creation of some interface which would transform  pointer type. No reinterpret_cast would be needed anywhere.

No, this is not good practice.  Such casts may "happen" to work, but they engage in undefined behavior; this "happens" to work because the end implementation uses binary identical layouts, but a compiler flag compiler update or a myraid of other reasons could break that.  In addition, non-binary data about the types doesn't line up; this can cause the compiler to make optimizations that are not valid, resulting in the program not doing what you want.
Use a std::span or similar.  A span is a non-owning reference to a range of contiguous values.
std::span<Target const*const> getTargets() const {
  return targets;
}

the span is a non-const view into an immutable range of pointers to const objects.  The top-level lack of const doesn't have much impact, as if they modify it they are just changing where they are looking, not the things being looked at.
Note that this cannot continue without bounds easily.  If you have a vector of vectors of vectors of pointers to non-const, you will end up having to allocate some memory and do some work in order to get the right "view" type that is const on all levels.
